# Change UIScrollView height to detect touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have an UITableView inside an UIScrollView and I want that the user will be able to scroll just when he touches the tableView (I have a map in the background and I want that the user will be able to integrate with the map when the tableView doesn't covers all of it.

I've tried to set scrollViewHeightConstraint.constant to scrollView.contentOffset.y on **-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView** but it didn't work, part of the map is still not touchable. Can anyone give me an advice what should I do? Thanks!

Screenshot: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAxby.png)

Comment: just add the map view to the header of the tableview setTableViewHeader, this: [_tableView setTableHeaderView:<#(UIView * _Nullable)#>], but this isn't easy to figure out, however it work, you just laod that uiview up with with whatever you want, and presto, you have liftoff

Comment: I don't want it to be a header, I want that the TableVIew will be a layer on top of the map, I don't want the map to move up automatically when the user scrolls.